# react-native init project issue

Tags: reactjs, project, native, init

I'm getting issue when first init project :

D:\react-native-tutorial\AwesomeProject3>react-native run-android

D:\react-native-tutorial\AwesomeProject3\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformat
ion\file\index.js:600
      throw err;
SyntaxError: D:/react-native-tutorial/AwesomeProject3/node_modules/react-native/
packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/index.js: You can only use Class Properties when the 'classProperties' plugin is enabled. (389:2)

anyone has ideas? thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I strongly recommend you to take a look at [How to Ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. If there is no context, no code, no examples, no explanation is very very difficult to help you.

Comment: @all thanks everyone , this is a new bug facebook introduced yesterday and the temp fix as below:


An issue has been filed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12542

npm uninstall babylon && npm install babylon@6.15.0 or update the package.json file to include "babylon": "6.15.0"